# Android: onRecieve's intent getSerializableExtra(String key) returns null

Tags: android, android-intent

So i have this code here;

```
myIntent.putExtra("schedule",serializableClass);
```

and this intent goes to my Broadcast Reciever and i did get that serializable as below,

```
public void  onRecieve(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Schedule s = (Schedule) intent.getSerializableExtra("schedule");
}
```

but it always returns even though when i put the Extras its not null, even checked before passing it on `myIntent.putExtra()` i really don't know what happen returns, why does it always returns null?.. anyone knows this problem?

Comment: is serializableClass implementing Serializable ?

Comment: yep all my classes are serializable

Answer (score 1):

The cast is wrong, i would be more easier to pass the serialized string and do deserialization. I' m using this class.

```
    public final class ObjectSerializer {

    private ObjectSerializer() {

    }

    public static String serialize(Serializable obj) throws IOException {
        if (obj == null)
            return "";
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serialObj);
            objStream.writeObject(obj);
            objStream.close();
            return encodeBytes(serialObj.toByteArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Serialization error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static Object deserialize(String str) throws IOException {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
            return null;
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    decodeBytes(str));
            ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(serialObj);
            return objStream.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Serialization error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static String encodeBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xF) + ('a')));
            strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i]) & 0xF) + ('a')));
        }

        return strBuf.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] decodeBytes(String str) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 2) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            bytes[i / 2] = (byte) ((c - 'a') << 4);
            c = str.charAt(i + 1);
            bytes[i / 2] += (c - 'a');
        }
        return bytes;
    }

}
```

after that use like this:

```
String scheduleSerialization = ObjectSerializer.serialize(schedule); 
myIntent.putExtra("schedule",scheduleSerialization);
```

the last thing to do is:

```
public void  onRecieve(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String serial =  intent.getStringExtra("schedule");
    if(serial!=null)
    Schedule s = (Schedule) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(serial) ;
}
```

Comment: hmmmm its a bit hard though, but i will try it out, btw is there any other way besides, serializable, to pass Objects to broadcast reciever through an intent?.. please do share

Comment: btw i've tried this on the different parts on my code, it doesn't return null, but on that part, where i put this code, its null, how come? is this because i didn't serailize it/>

Answer (score 0):

Using Serializable on Android is discouraged because it is slow. If you look at the android source code you will see that

- the usually break down the information into multiple keys and send them as primitive types (Integer, String, etc..)
- when that can't be done, the will use a Parcelable object

Comment: so u mean to say Parcelable is best use?

Comment: Parcelable is better than Serializable. But my answer says that for "small" objects & no composition of objects, you're better off writing the instance variables of the object into different elementary elements of the Bundle (putStringExtra, putIntegerExtra...)

Comment: ohhh so writing or passing (the members of the objects) them one by one is better compared to passing them as a whole?

Comment: Well if you have 20 such members, it may be worth doing it with a custom Parcelable (i.e. serialize yourself). If not, stick to that, yes